# React useCallback called before useState issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

When they press submit I am trying to alert the user as to what option they chose based on the `CheckBox` .

However I am having a problem  in which when I check the checkbox of `today` and `tomorrow` the actual state outside the handleSubmit function is true however in the `handleSubmit` function both `today` and `tomorrow` are false and I don't know how to get the actual state to render in `useCallBack` hook. Therefore `today` and `tomorrow` in useCallBack will always be false

Please can someone see where I am going wrong and assist me with this hook problem. Thank You!!!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'
import { Alert } from 'react-native'

const Choose = (props) => {
    const [today, setToday] = useState(false)
    const [tommorow, setTommorow] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        props.navigation.setParams({ handleSubmit: handleSubmit })
    }, [handleSubmit])

    console.log(`today is ${today}`) // this works and is changed by the check box
    const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
        if (today == true){
            console.log(`today is ${today}`) // today from outise this function is never true
            
            Alert.alert('You selected today')
        }else if (tommorow == true){
            Alert.alert('You selected tommorow')
        }
    }, [today, tommorow])

    return (
        <View>
            <CheckBox
                checked={world}
                onPress={() => setToday(!today)}
                title='Today'
            />
            <CheckBox
                onPress={() => setTommorow(!tommorow)}
                title='Tommorow'
            />
        </View>
    )
}
export default ChooseToAdd

Choose.navigationOptions = () => {
    const submit = navigationData.navigation.getParam('handleSubmit')
    return {
        headerRight: () =>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={submit}>
                <Text>Submit</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    }
}
```

Comment: If you refactor the code to put the declaration for handleSubmit outside of the Choose component and completely drop the useEffect does that do anything different?

eg: const handlesubmit = (today, tomorrow) => {
if (today == true){
            console.log(`today is ${today}`) // today from outise this function is never true            
            Alert.alert('You selected today')
        }else if (tommorow == true){
            Alert.alert('You selected tommorow')
        }
}

Comment: Yeah it won’t have access to the today and tomorrow state

Comment: pass the state in so it has access to it.

Comment: Please show me because I really don’t know how to pass the state to it . I’d really appreciate it . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why not change this

```
    useEffect(() => {
        props.navigation.setParams({ handleSubmit: handleSubmit })
    }, [handleSubmit])

    console.log(`today is ${today}`) // this works and is changed by the check box
    const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
        if (today == true){
            console.log(`today is ${today}`) // today from outise this function is never true
            
            Alert.alert('You selected today')
        }else if (tommorow == true){
            Alert.alert('You selected tommorow')
        }
    }, [today, tommorow])
```

to this

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleSubmit = () => {
            if (today == true){
                Alert.alert('You selected today')
            }else if (tommorow == true){
                Alert.alert('You selected tommorow')
            }
        }
        props.navigation.setParams({ handleSubmit: handleSubmit })
    },[today, tommorow])
```

Comment: How come? did you try it? there is no reason it will cause a loop.

Comment: Yeah I did try it and then when the code runs it is causing the emulator to freeze so therefore I think it is running infinitely. I think it is also because in the else statement in my code i am dispatching an action and maybe that's causing the loop

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to what this does:
One of the suggestions I've read elsewhere is to move functions declarations outside of the scope of the component as this makes them constant without needing to use useCallback.
I'm thinking this will exhibit the same behavior though...I'm thinking that the setParams / submit handler is going to have a stale closure over state?

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react'
    import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'
    import { Alert } from 'react-native'
    
    function handleSubmit(today,tomorrow) {
    return () => {
            if (today == true){
                console.log(`today is ${today}`)             
                Alert.alert('You selected today')
            }else if (tommorow == true){
                Alert.alert('You selected tommorow')
            }
    
    };
        }
    
    const Choose = (props) => {
        const [today, setToday] = useState(false)
        const [tommorow, setTommorow] = useState(false)
    
        props.navigation.setParams({ handleSubmit: handleSubmit(today,tomorrow) });

const handleTodayclicked() => {
setToday(!today);
props.navigation.setParams({ handleSubmit: handleSubmit(today,tomorrow) });
};

const handleTomorrowClicked() => {
setTommorow(!tommorow);
props.navigation.setParams({ handleSubmit: handleSubmit(today,tomorrow) });
}; 
   
        return (
            <View>
                <CheckBox
                    checked={world}
                    onPress={() => handleTodayclicked()}
                    title='Today'
                />
                <CheckBox
                    onPress={() => handleTomorrowClicked()}
                    title='Tommorow'
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
    export default ChooseToAdd
    
    Choose.navigationOptions = () => {
        const submit = navigationData.navigation.getParam('handleSubmit')
        return {
            headerRight: () =>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={submit}>
                    <Text>Submit</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'll try this . I am trying to do `props.navigation.navigate()` in the handleSubmit function so where should I put this (I did not include the `navigation.navigate()` in the actual code because I thought it was necessary.)However If i take `handleSubmit` out of choose then where do i put the navigation code?

Comment: hmmm...pass it to handleSubmit() similarly to today & tomorrow? actually...sec - I have an update...in the onPress handlers have them call functions that update props.navigation..